# tftp PUT fail with TFTPD32 (atftp, and tftp works)

Tags: tftp

I configure tftpd on my embedded system with command:

```
# udpsvd -E 0 69 tftpd -c /flash0/app/Binary/
```

Everything works fine when I use linux apps (tftp, atftp) as clients. 
But with windows tool (TFTPD32 by Ph.Jounin) - preffered in company I can't PUT file into server.

Correct trace (few lines):

```
# sending 4 bytes
00 04 00 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 4 bytes
00 04 00 01 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0002
sending 4 bytes
00 04 00 02 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0003
sending 4 bytes
```

Error trace :

```
# sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
sending 10 bytes
00 06 74 73 69 7a 65 00 30 00 
received 516 bytes: 0003 0001
tftpd: timeout
tftpd: malformed packet
tftpd: malformed packet
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. It is tftp implementation dependand question. 
I use one from ddwrt/busybox distro.
I needed to disable FEATURE_TFTP_BLOCKSIZE, and avoid tftp_get_option("blksize"...).